# Python. Как дождаться окончания копирования файла и не словить Permission denied

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня простой скрипт, он постоянно проверяет папку если там появился новый файл, забирает его (далее бот кидает его в группу в телеге, думаю это не важно).

Пример кода целиком кидать лучше не буду, только запутаю, думаю и так понятно задумка не сложная.

Так вот, если попытаться забрать файл в тот момент когда он копируется(в процессе копирования) упадёт "PermissionError".

Я не профи поэтому всё обмазал циклом и перехватами исключений со слипами, этот способ почему то мне не кажется правильным.

```
for _ in range(6):
                try:
                    with open(main_path + last_app, 'rb') as f:
                        bot.send_document(id_chat, f, caption=f'Пакет от {change_date}')
                        break
                except PermissionError:
                    print(f'Упало исключение {last_app} - {change_date}')
                    sleep(3)
                    continue
                except Exception as err:
                    bot.send_message(id_chat, text=f'Чет не получается')
                    break
```

Заранее извиняюсь, если вопрос слишком тупой, но как грамотно дождаться пока файл докопируется?

Comment: Я бы смотрел время создания/изменения файла и ждал какой-то отрезок времени отталкиваясь от этого времени. Файл может быть занят некоторое время и после закрытия, например, антивирусом, который захотел проверить что это тут у нас такое поменялось.

Comment: а что говорит, например, os.access() на этот файл, если он еще копируется?

Comment: возможно поступить проще. если файл находится в процессе копирования, то его размер будет постоянно меняться. оставляете слип в 1 и на следующей итерации сравниваете размер до и сейчас. если он изменился то файл копируется.

Comment: @alex Ну это тоже не гарантия. Лучше какие-то атрибуты файла всё же смотреть

Comment: @alex "os.path.getsize()" - сразу показывает правильный размер, как только копирование начинается

Comment: посмотрите несколько решений там https://coderoad.ru/32092645/Python-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%81-windows-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F